# Ctrl + "numpad -" to create boolean subtract doesn't work here

Tags: modifiers, keymap

I create a new project, duplicate the cube, move it a bit, press ctrl + "numpad -", nothing happens. On my other computer it works. It's a fresh new blender installation. I checked preferences/keymap, there's no boolean. Any ideas? The ctrl key is definitely working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> is a *BoolTool* shortcut, you need to activate the *BoolTool* addon:

[image]